# Writing a PFObject to disk

Tags: ios, parse-platform

When I looked up how to write a `PFObject` to disk, I found some quite complicated stuff.
The simplest option I found was to write encoding and decoding functions and then use `NSKeyedArchiver` (which I have not tried yet because I want to make sure I'm using the most adequate solution).
More complicated options involved third-party libraries so as to sync with Core Data.

Parse.com engineers said they are working on features that will make [offline usage work better](https://parse.com/questions/persistent-store-of-pfobject-pffile), but nothing is there yet AFAIK.

However, the `PFUser` class has a `currentUser` method with the following description and signature:

```
/*!
 Gets the currently logged in user from disk and returns an instance of it.
 @result Returns a PFUser that is the currently logged in user. If there is none, returns nil.
 */
+ (instancetype)currentUser;
```

It seems that whatever is in this method should be a good way to work with a `PFObject` on disk.
Is there any way to know what the technology behind this method (and behind all the `logIn*`methods in which the saving must be happening)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `PFUser.currentUser()` actually just returns a static class variable, [as seen here](https://github.com/OneMoreThing/ParseKit/blob/master/ParseKit/PFUser.m).